# C# WPF ObservableCollection не изменяет вид когда изменяю обьект по ссылке на MemberwiseClone

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

Пытаюсь изменить View Model который привязан к DataGrid

```
protected ObservableCollection<Object> _objects;
public ObservableCollection<Object> Objects {
  get => this._objects;
  set => SetProperty(ref this._objects, value);
}
```

> ItemsSource="{Binding Objects, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"

Во вторую View Model передаю Object, клонирую его

```
this.Object = (Object)this._previousObject.Clone();
```

и пытаюсь измененный обьект склонировать назад

```
this.PreviousObject = (Object)this.Object.Clone();
```

Clone

```
public object Clone() {
  return this.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

Object и Previous Object

```
protected Object _object;
public Object Object {
  get => this._object;
  set => SetProperty(ref this._object, value);
}

protected Object _previousObject;
public Object PreviousObject {
  get => this._previousObject;
  set => SetProperty(ref this._previousObject, value);
}
```

после чего DataGridRow не изменяет себя, но если обратиться к коллекции
т.е.

```
Objects[index] = (Object)this.Object.Clone();
```

то все изменяется нормально

В чем разница между PreviousObject и Objects[index]?

Comment: тем, что это разные инстансы? И на них ведут разные ссылки? Покажите код работы с DataGrid

Comment: Ничего не понял. Почему DataGridRow должен изменяться, когда вы изменяете какие-то Object и PreviousObject? Содержимое ObservableCollection<Object> Objects ведь при этом никак не изменяется

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что вы путаете ссылку на объект с объектом.
Когда вы элемент массива записываете в переменную _previousObject, то вы копируете ссылку на объект, операция клонирования создает новый объект с новой ссылкой, которая и записывается в переменную _previousObject. К оригинальному массиву это не имеет никакого отношения. Выглядит в памяти это примерно вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.s. Элементы массива, как видно из рисунка, это тоже не объекты, а ссылки на объекты, поэтому, когда вы делаете Objects[index] = (Object)this.Object.Clone(); вы меняете ссылку в основном массиве и у вас все нормально перерисовывается.

Comment: тоесть мне нужно использовать IndexOf и засетить по нему после изменения или есть другие пути?

Comment: Вариантов куча. В чем идея изменения элемента коллекции одного класса во вне? Может вам проще метод из внешнего класса вызывать, который будет отвечать за то, чтобы склонировать (зачем-то, это место для меня самое непонятное) элемент сам в себя. В чем у вас состоит потребность? Может есть более простые варианты,ч ем клонирование объекта туда-сюда.

Comment: мне просто нужно изменить обьект в отдельном окне, у меня есть DataGrid с ObservableCollection, DataGridRow имеет Context Menu где при клике я получаю DataGridRow DataContext т.е выделеный Object и какбы DataGridRow после изменения его Object в отдельном окне нужно чтобы обновил записи в столбиках которые изменились

Comment: Передавайте объект из контекста, меняйте его и если он (а точнее его класс) поддерживает интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged, то вы все изменения нормально увидите. Вот здесь посмотрите: https://losev-al.blogspot.com/2012/07/inotifypropertychanged.html